# Bootstrap CDN classes conflict?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

I notice that when I use bootstrap in my project, some of the classes are applied to my code. Is there a way I can only use the bootstrap classes I want using CDN? 
Here's the code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Then below I have:

```
<ul>
<li>Some text here...</li>
</ul>
```

and when I check the chrome debugger, it inherits properties for ul:
[image]

I know I can manually force my own classes to get rid of it, but it would be tedious.

Comment: Change the class names in your code so they don't match the ones bootstrap uses, or create overrides for your versions.

Comment: My question is a bit unclear so I should probably clarify by saying that the classes in Bootstrap are cascading into my code rather than conflicting class names.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: I'll make my post more descriptive with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use bootstrap's CSS from CDN and only apply the styles to certain elements only.

The only way to exclude some styles is to **recompile** twitter-bootstrap and leave out all styles you don't want, respectively only include the one's you want.

You can download the source [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).

Please note that recompiling bootstrap requires a Less compiler.